# How do I solve this boundary-value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

There is no exact answer for this question, but I'm having trouble with guessing what the author intended.

> Solve the boundary-value problem:
>
> $u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx} + u$
>
> Boundary condition: $u(x,0)=f(x), u_t(x,0)=0, u(0,t)=0, u(l,t)=0$.

This problem is an exercise in an elementary differential equation text and I don't get what the author intended.

Here's how I tried this:

Set $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$.

Then, $\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T'' - T}{c^2 T}$.

Thus for some constant $\lambda$, $X''+\lambda X =0 $ and $T'' + (c^2\lambda - 1)T=0$.

So $\lambda=\lambda_n=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{l^2}$ and $X(x)=X_n(x)=\sin (\frac{n\pi x}{l})$.

However, I have a trouble with finding $T_n$. There may be a case that $c^2 \lambda_n - 1 \leq 0$ for some $n$. So I think it should be assumed that $c^2 > l^2/\pi^2$.

If this is not the author intended, how do I solve this?

Comment: What you have stated is true. It seems that everything depends on the constant $c$. But I think there should be some typo! I suspect that it should be $u_t$ instead of $u$ in the PDE.

Comment: @H.R. which one do you mean? That $c^2>l^2/\pi^2$?

Comment: The $u$ in the PDE. $c$ is some material property which is given based on the medium that the wave is propagating in it.  So there may be any cases for $c$. :)

Comment: @H.R. How do I solve this when $c^2 \leq l^2/\pi^2$? In this case, $T_n$ may not be represented as a linear combination cosine and sine functions for some $n$. This is what exactly I'm having trouble with..

Comment: Go to some ODE book and see the solutions for $y''+ky=0$ in different cases for $k$. :) If $k \gt 0$ you have harmonic functions. If $k \lt 0$ you have hyperbolic functions. If $k=0$ you have a linear function. :)

Comment: @H.R. No, I know that. The question is, if $c^2\leq l^2/\pi^2$, then $T_n$ may not be represented as a linear combination of cosine and sine functions for some $n$. Thus $f(x)=u(x,0)= O(x)+ \sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \sin (n\pi x /l)$. So we cannot find such $a_n$ in terms of $f(x)$ since it is not the Fourier series of $f$. This is what I'm asking.

Comment: What! At each case, $T_n$ is a linear combination of two functions! It does not need to be $\sin$ or $\cos$! :) You just need Fourier series in terms of the variable $x$. It doesn't matter what $T_n(t)$ is!

Comment: @H.R. Yes, for any $c$, $T_n$ can be represented as a linear combination of two functions. However, if $c^2> l^2/\pi^2$, it is a linear combination of cosine and sine. I'm asking this **since $T_n$ may not be represented as so**. I know all you said above, but that does not answer my question..

Comment: So, I think you have not expressed your question well! :)

Comment: So let's think of an explicit example. Say the boundary conditions are given as above and set $l=1$ and $c^2= 1/4\pi ^2$. Would you explicitly solve this one as an answer?

Comment: Ok I will delete this post and repost it again with more details. Thank you.

Comment: No need to delete. Just edit this post. :)